# How to get AdSense on a Google Code project page?

Tags: adsense, google-code

I must admit that I don't really know if this is the right place to ask this question, however: in your knowledge it possible to have AdSense on a Google Code project page? I have tried searching Google for information about this, but it gets very confused by the query (that's because the AdSense API is on Google Code as well!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this method that allows you to put ad gadgets with AdSense on your Google Code project home and wiki pages: http://code.google.com/p/gprojecthosting-adsense/

It works very well for me, I must say.

Just keep in mind that the gadget renders in an iframe with little if any content, so the relevant ads as inferred by Google will be mostly (or only) interest-based.

Answer (score 0):

I use this one https://code.google.com/p/gcodeadsense/

works like a charm. Mind this: just use the number from the client code and skip  "ca-pub-".